# Computing age today from date of birth variable (R)

Tags: r, date

I have a dataframe with information on date of birth by individual id.

```
mydf <- data.frame(id=c(1,2),
                   dtbirth=as.Date(c("2012-01-01","2013-04-01")))
```

I would like to compute the age of the individuals as of today. The code below seems to work but outputs "days" to the new variable `age`

```
mydf %>%
  mutate(age=floor((today()-dtbirth)/365))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can wrap with `as.integer/as.numeric` to remove the `class` attribute `difftime`

```
mydf %>%
  mutate(age= as.integer(floor((today()-dtbirth)/365)))
```

-output

```
#  id    dtbirth age
#1  1 2012-01-01   9
#2  2 2013-04-01   8
```

---

By default, when we use the `-`, the `difftime` picks up the unit by `"auto"`

```
mydf %>%
   mutate(age = today() - dtbirth)
#  id    dtbirth       age
#1  1 2012-01-01 3430 days
#2  2 2013-04-01 2974 days
```

If we need more fine control, use `difftime` itself and specify the `units`

```
mydf %>%
     mutate(age = difftime(today(), dtbirth, units = 'weeks'))
#  id    dtbirth            age
#1  1 2012-01-01 490.0000 weeks
#2  2 2013-04-01 424.8571 weeks
```

We cannot have `units` greater than 'weeks' as the available options are

> difftime(time1, time2, tz,
> units = c("auto", "secs", "mins", "hours",
> "days", "weeks"))

and it is mentioned as

> Units such as "months" are not possible as they are not of constant length. To create intervals of months, quarters or years use seq.Date or seq.POSIXt.